# conversion from gis to lat/long give me big trouble in charset

Tags: php, arrays, string, utf-8, symbols

i've a string like

```
$input="16°28'60,00''"
```

thats is on my db and stored as `TEXT utf8_general_ci`
im trying to convert it to decimal/lat-long system. So I write a function that splice the input and convert it.
Im using $input as an array, and when is on position 2, I have a strange result thats broke my function:

```
$input[2]---> 'b"Â"'
```

in position 2 there is the "°"
the next row check if esist "°" but due this error can works

```
if($tempD == iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", '°')
```

how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the DB string is always the same, just grab the digits out and you don't need to bother with the degrees, minutes, seconds.

```
$input = "16°28'60,00''";
preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $input, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 60
            [3] => 00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 60
            [3] => 00
        )

)
```

Now you have each digit and you can convert it easily.